# How to draw an image on a specific tile?

Tags: java, openstreetmap

I'm trying to draw an image on a specific tile by rendering tile maps from a tile server in Java. I know the zoom level, latitude, longitude and the tile number. The tiles are being rendered and represented on the screen without any issues. Now, suppose I want to place a marker say at 'x' degree latitude and 'y' degree longitude and ensure it stays there at that coordinate for all zoom levels. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following page could help you: it provides all necessary steps on how to place a marker on a single tile depending on zoom level, latitude, longitude. Unfortunately, the link is in German, but if you use Google Chrome and have it translate to English, the results look pretty decent.

http://www.netzwolf.info/kartografie/osm/tilebrowser?lat=51.154478&lon=6.868858&zoom=14

You can even set your own marker by clicking on the tile. This will automatically update all the calculations on the page.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for.